# Authenticate user using our database

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-phone, wcf-security, windows-10-mobile

I read about using a WCF service but past experience reminds me that the **service** could not be used with a username/password successfully which means if someone found out the URL to the service they could make calls without providing any form of username/password to allow them authenticate to the service (if so please could you provide me with a working sample to follow?)

Is there a built-in authentication system that i could use to build a Windows Phone 8.1/10 app (preferably a Universal app) which allows the user to be authenticated with details on a database hosted on our server (A bit like ASP .Net Identity)?

Azure is not free so rather not use this :-(

Comment: WCF can authenticate with a username and password. [On this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff405740.aspx) under **Authenticate Clients and Services** see the bullet point **Basic** . You can actually use ASP.NET Idententy with that on the server side to validate the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

*service could not be used with a username/password successfully which means if someone found out the URL to the service they could make calls without providing any form of username/password to allow them authenticate to the service*? I think it depends, if you didn't add any security mechanism to your service, then they can just use it without probing. There are lot of security mechanism that WCF offers some of it are username/password, windows authentication and certificate etc. If you want to validate username and password in the database you can start with [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565(v=vs.110).aspx).